# The use of the present simple and the future simple after "if-clauses" when making threats

Tags: difference, present-simple, future-constructions

Would you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the present simple and the future simple in the context below?

> If you don't pay up, I **file** a lawsuit.
>
> If you don't pay up, I **will file** a lawsuit.

I hear both the present simple and future simple sentence in this type sentences very often. And to me, a non native speaker, both sentences mean the same. But, my gut feeling tells me there might me a difference in meaning.

I've refered to grammar books for an answer but couldn't find it for this specific context.

Comment: Imho, the stylistic choice to use *Present* tense in such contexts adds "immediacy" to the ***consequence*** clause. It also carries a stronger sense of ***inevitability*** - as if you're citing some kind of "natural law" along the lines of *If you heat water to 100°C, **it boils*** (which to my ear sounds far more "decisive" than *...it **will** boil*). Compare with, for example, ***You snooze, you lose***, where you'll virtually never encounters *[If] you snooze, you **will** lose*.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the second (*I will file*) is natural, except that nearly any English speaker will say *I'll* file, unless they are stressing "will" (*I **will** file*).

The first (*I file*) seems odd to me, and I suspect that you are mishearing *I'll file* as *I file*. Some people might say *I file* - to me that sounds colloquial and rather American.

Comment: "*When* customers don't pay, I always *file* a lawsuit." I think the present tense can be used in the subordinate clause if the main clause begins with "when".

Comment: I agree that with OP's *specific* example, a Future tense "consequences" clause is probably more likely. But there's nothing wrong with Present tense, and to my mind it's actually *better* if you want that consequence to sound "threatening / inevitable" rather than just a description of how you ***expect*** to react ***if*** the specified condition arises.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: with _always_, it's not future anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that the present sounds more thratening. It sounds like an American gangster to me.